# Calculating the Big-O notation of this Ensemble consisting of multiple classifiers

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I have a model shown below, and I am trying to calculate its overall computational complexity (Big-O notation).

[image]

In this model, classifiers of type "A" have a time complexity of `O(mN)`, where N is the number instances in the dataset, and m is a constant variable determined by the classifier "A" (I am trying to produce  a minimal working example so the question can be clear. Let me know if more info is needed about m). Classifier "B" has a time complexity of `O(N^2)`, where N is the number of instances in the dataset.

This model is basically an ensemble classifier consisting of n-number of "A" classifiers, and m-number of "B" classifiers. The final decision is based on a simple weighted majority vote. To determine the weights, I trained the system using a dataset, while assigning randomly generated weight combinations to the classifiers "A" and "B". The best weight combination that is selected for the system is the one that gives the best detection accuracy on the training subset of the dataset. This selected weight combination is then used also during the testing of the system.

Being new to algorithms and time complexity analysis, I was only able to compute or research on the time complexities of the individual classifies which I presented/stated above, but what is the overall computational complexity of the system given the n+m classifiers and the majority voting phase (final decision phase)?

Comment: Do you have `n` classifiers of type `A`, and `m` classifiers of type `B` ?

Comment: Yes @Tony Tannous.

Comment: How is the set distributed among the classifiers ?

Comment: The classifiers all get the same instance from the dataset. See the diagram, you can deduce the answer to your question from the fig.  x_i is sent to all classifiers.

Comment: Thanks, @TonyTannous, yeah I will also wait for for the assurance.

Comment: I edited to add a tighter bound. I think it's a correct answer but I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Let `a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, ...., a_n` be the constants generated by the `n` classifiers of type **A**.

Let `a_max = max{a_1, a_2, a_3, ...., a_n}`

The time complexity for the `n` classifiers of type **A** is: `O(n*a_max*N)`

---

`m` classifiers of type **B**, each running in time complexity `O(N^2)`

For the total `m` classifiers it would be: `O(m*N^2)`

---

Time Complexity: **O(m*N^2 + n*a_max*N)**

---

You could have also written it:

```
O(m*N^2 + (a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n)*N), a tighter bound.
```